# Access MongoDB from Talend

Tags: mongodb, connection, talend

I'm trying to access mongoDB from talend. I set all parameters ok since it can connect without any problem.

The problem is that I got the following error:

```
Exception in component tMongoDBInput_2
java.lang.RuntimeException: db error [not authorized for query on lvdb.users]
```

If I login in shell with the same user/password used in Talend I can query on that DB. Why it fails?

Comment: do you have any other database in this mongodb - can you try against those - to narrow down the problem - if its with all objects or only specific ones

Comment: I've solved it bypassing authentication. In /etc/mongod.conf I disabled authentication (not a true solution) but atleast works.

Comment: Disabling authentication is not a good idea. This could be connected to the authentication mechanism you selected in Talend.